# Grep one field in each line of a file in another file, unifying results

Tags: bash, file, grep

I have a file A with contents

```
id_7 name_7
id_10 name_10
....
```

and another file B with all ids:

```
id_1 ssn_1
id_2 ssn_2
.....
```

I want to grep the first field (id_7, id_10...) in the second file, however I want the matches to be output like this:

```
id_1 ssn_1 name_1
....
```

How do I do this quickly (million of lines in each file) ?

Comment: search here for exampls of the `join` cmd.

Comment: `join -j 1 file2 file1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `join` deal with each line of each file, it depends on the common field, so it should be sorted to have the common field to be the same.

```
join -j 1 <(sort -k 1 file1) <(sort -k 1 file2)
```